# concat in FSharp.Core.String vs Concat in System.String

Tags: string, f#

I noticed that there is a lowercase `String.concat` in `Microsoft.FSharp.Core` and an uppercase `System.String.Concat` with several overloads. Intellisense picks one or the other if I type `String.c` or `System.String.C`

Are the `String.xyz` functions in `Microsoft.FSharp.Core` preferable to  `System.String.Xyz` functions or the other way around? What are each type of function advantages and disadvantages?

In general, what are the advantages and disadvantages of using functions in FSharp.Core?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure that these 2 are equivalent:

FSharp's [`String.concat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/string.concat-function-%5Bfsharp%5D) is used to join a sequence of strings into a single string with a delimeter:

```
let strings = [ "tomatoes"; "bananas"; "apples" ]
let fullString = String.concat ", " strings
printfn "%s" fullString
```

`System.String.Concat` is used to concatenate 2 (or more) separate strings together.

`System.String.Join` is the same as FSharp's `String.concat` - it's just a wrapper for it [actually](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/blob/cbe88a8acb16e60979ab67d073d3c0527d089376/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/string.fs#L22):

```
[<CompiledName("Concat")>]
let concat sep (strings : seq<string>) =  
    String.Join(sep, strings)
```

---

When writing F# you will find it more idiomatic to call F# functions over the ones from other .NET assemblies. You can partially apply F# functions for example, you can't to that with .NET method calls.

e.g. a function that always concats with a space can be defined like so:

```
let concatWithSpace xs = 
  String.concat " " xs
```

Which becomes more useful if you model it as part of your Domain, e.g. instead of `concatWithSpace`, it could be called `formatReportElements` or something with meaning.

Comment: So is the advantage of `FSharp.Core.String` that its functions that take multiple arguments are capable of partial application, while multi-argument functions in `System.String` are not since they must take their arguments wrapped in parentheses? (If a `System.String` function only takes one argument the parentheses can be skipped)
Are there any other advantages?

Comment: The big advantage of the "curried" form is that partial application lets you include that function in a pipeline chain. E.g., `[ 1..10 ] |> List.filter isOdd |> List.map (fun n -> n * 10) |> List.map (sprintf "%d") |> String.concat ", "` produces the string `"10, 30, 50, 70, 90"` (if you've defined `isOdd`, of course). Whereas to use `System.String.Join` in that pipeline, you'd have to write `|> (fun lst -> System.String.Join(", ", lst))`. I'd rather write `String.concat ", "` instead of `(fun lst -> System.String.Join(", ", lst))`: it's much easier to read and understand what the former does.